# How does Back End and Front End work together?

Tags: php, laravel, frontend, backend

I learned how to program in php years ago but i realised i was so outdated, but now im getting up to date. I'm working with Laravel now, only back-ending, so i just learned MVC model and all that stuff.

Me and my friend (who is a front end developer), we want to work together in a website using Laravel. so my question is.. how does this works?, a few questions to throw out there:

- Do we both connect to the same server and work there?
- How do we work together? he just care about views folder and that's it?
- He tells me the variables that he needs? for the views?

As you can see, i have no clue of how team-work comes together.

just out of curiosity.. how do you learn this? is there a working method detailed for this?

Comment: see this `http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Do we both connect to the same server and work there?**

No, you don't need to work on the same server during development, but you both have to work on the same codebase. Don't worry, you can use Git, SVN, or others to work on the same codebase in different computers easily. Finally you will have a single codebase which will be ready to deployed on online hosting.

Following are two simple guides to using Git as a Version Control System:

[Git - The Simple Guide](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

[CodeSchool - Try Git](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)

[What is Version Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control)

---

**How do we work together? he just care about views folder and that's it?**

Not just views, but he can work in the **views** folder and in an another folder called the **public** folder which will contain your **CSS, JavaScript and images**. Most probably the front-end developer wont need to touch other parts.

**Important:** In order to work as a front-end developer in a Laravel project, some one needs to learn the syntax of [Laravel Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) which is a template language for PHP and is extremely **easy to learn**.

[Blade Templates - Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)

[Simple Laravel Blade Templates - Scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-layouts-using-blade)

---

**He tells me the variables that he needs? for the views?**

Mostly yes and vise versa, you will write your core logic in your **models** and will access them through your **controllers**, and then you can pass the **variables** from controllers to your **views**.

Comment: Excelent Answer! just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I have not used laravel but,
The first bullet: If you want to see any results from your collaborative coding, you will have to be on the same server editing the same files where you are hosting. Or you can use a localhost and just keep sending each other updated files. Don't forget to archive...I am sure you know that though.

Broad question. Not sure how else to help.

Comment: Part of your information is objectively false.

Comment: The entire question has an array of answers for each bullet. I tried to give him a starting point. What part of "editing the same files" is false ? That seemed to be his question.